# get the pid of specified process name from pstree by using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pstree

I am using pstree to get a set of process and the result will be like

processA(123)---processB(124)---processC(125)---processTarget(126)---processD(127)

I would like to use the keyword "processTarget" to get the pid, that is 126.

The reason why i chose the pstree is that I will send SIGTSTP signal and SIGCONT to this set of process.

How could I do that? Is there any easy to do it?

Note:The processTarget(126) is not in the fixed position, therefore I could not use awk to get the PID.

Comment: Don't use `pstree` use `pgrep`.

Comment: @EtanReisner  the reason why i chose the pstree is that I will send SIGTSTP signal and SIGCONT to this set of process.

Comment: I'm confused. You asked how to get the pid of a specific process from that output (namely `126`) how is that not what `pgrep` does? What do the rest of the processes have to do with anything? And if you need their pids also why is that not part of your question?

Comment: @EtanReisner  Thanks for your answer. pgrep is the new staff for me. I just know it from you. It is much more useful for me to solve the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep`.

`<pstree command> | grep -P -o 'processTarget\([0-9]+\)'`

`-P` means use Perl regex
`-o` mean only return the match

`man grep` for more details

If the goal is to get just the id you can continue this approach to return just the integer

`<pstree command> | grep -P -o 'processTarget\([0-9]+\)' | grep -P -o '[0-9]+'`

Comment: Yea, I never knew about that. Seems perfect for this. Not sure if I should leave this answer or not.

Comment: @dan08 It still helps me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy with **parameter expansion/substring extraction**. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

##plist=$( pstree something )  # actual command to fill plist

plist="processA(123)---processB(124)---processC(125)---processTarget(126)---processD(127)"

temp="${plist##*processTarget(}"
ptgtnum="${temp%%)--*}"

printf "\n  processTarget = %s\n\n" "$ptgtnum"

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash ptgt.sh

  processTarget = 126
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider `sed`:

```
echo 'processA(123)---processB(124)---processC(125)---processTarget(126)---processD(127)' \ | sed 's/.*processTarget(\([0-9]*\)).*/\1/'
126
```